# Load (import) an existing non-sample CVAT Project to fiftyone as Dataset

Tags: cvat, fiftyone

I am trying

```
import fiftyone as fo
dataset = fo.load_dataset("import_test")
```

the project which exists and have such project name, I've created in CVAT before.

Such call was used in https://githubhelp.com/voxel51/fiftyone/issues/1611

but I am getting

> ValueError: Dataset 'import_test' not found

In the documentation:
https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/integrations/cvat.html
examples and other questions:

1. https://colab.research.google.com/github/voxel51/fiftyone-examples/blob/master/examples/pytorch_detection_training.ipynb#scrollTo=5crNDNsRWdPT
2. [Uploading large dataset from FiftyOne to CVAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797248/uploading-large-dataset-from-fiftyone-to-cvat)
3. https://medium.com/voxel51/loading-open-images-v6-and-custom-datasets-with-fiftyone-18b5334851c3

there are only usage of sample fiftyone dataet:

```
dataset = foz.load_zoo_dataset("...")
```

which works correctly for me as CVAT server connection check, but don't suit my work needs.
In
https://towardsdatascience.com/tools-to-annotate-and-improve-computer-vision-datasets-f9b99cdb0e04
using local machine stored dataset

```
dataset = fo.Dataset.from_dir("...")
```

Can I load already created project initially created in CVAT from server,
what argument is supposed to be used except it's CVAT's name of project?
Is it possible or it has to be initially  fiftyone dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`fiftyone.utils.cvat.import_annotations()`](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/integrations/cvat.html#importing-existing-tasks) method to import labels that are already in a CVAT project or task into a FiftyOne Dataset.

Note that in order to use `fo.load_dataset()`, the dataset needs to already exist in FiftyOne. You can initialize an empty dataset like so as shown in [the import annotations example](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/integrations/cvat.html#importing-existing-tasks):

```py
dataset = fo.Dataset("my-dataset-name")
```

Then, you can call `import_annotations()`, providing a project name and optionally a `data_path` and `export_media=True` to download all of the media from your project to a local directory as well as all of the labels in your project, then import them into the dataset you just created.

```py
dataset = fo.Dataset("my-dataset-name")
fouc.import_annotations(
    dataset,
    project_name=project_name,
    data_path="/tmp/cvat_import",
    download_media=True,
)
```

If your media already exists in disk, then see the linked example for how to provide a `data_map` mapping the CVAT filename to filepath of the media on the local disk.

Comment: Thank you! I've got an issue with this receipt for all projs, which are non-empty https://pastebin.com/khHp1jFf

Comment: Can you verify that the `project_name` matches what is in CVAT? If that is still giving you issues, try to provide the `project_id` instead of the `project_name`.

Comment: Thank you, with Id option smth was loaded. The original question resolved, however there are some issues in completeness of loaded.

Comment: Great, feel free to open an issue on Github with more details about your use case: https://github.com/voxel51/fiftyone